# Input validation for a set of string values in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm in the process of making a GPA calculator, which will prompt the user to enter their class name, credit worth, and expected letter grade for each class. I'm having problems coming up with a valid way to validate the user's input when prompted to enter an expected letter grade. Here's what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("What grade did you earn in the class: A, A-, B+, B, B-, C+, C, C-, D+, D, or F?");
            String[] grades ={"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "F"};
            firstGrade = scanner.nextLine();

            while (!firstGrade.equals(grades)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please type a valid letter grade");
                firstGrade = scanner.nextLine();
            }
             switch(firstGrade){
                case "A":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 4.0");
                    break;
                case "A-":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 3.7");
                    break;
                case "B+":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 3.3");
                    break;
                case "B":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 3.0");
                    break;
                case "B-":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 2.7");
                    break;
                case "C+":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 2.3");
                    break;
                case "C":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 2.0");
                    break;
                case "C-":
                        System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 1.7");
                    break;
                case "D+":
                    System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 1.3");
                break;
                case "D":
                    System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 1.0");
                break;
                case "F":
                    System.out.println("Your GPA from " + firstClass +" is a 0.0");
                break;
             }
```

I'm trying to use an array in the process but not sure if that's the best way to go about it. All I want is for the user to be alerted when they don't enter in a proper letter grade and then prompt them to until they do.

I've tried using `default` in the switch statement but can't get the program to validate input after the first time they fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `firstGrade` is a `String`, and `grades` is a `String[]`, so `firstGrade.equals(grades)` will *never* be true.

Comment: Very true Andreas, I overlooked that I was comparing a String to an array of Strings, bid difference. Thanks for pointing that out, goes to show the JAVA syntax is what I've come to learn, very forgiving but also deceiving.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you use a `Map<String, Double>` and eliminate the `switch` altogether. You can use that `Map` to display your options if you use a `LinkedHashMap` (since it preserves insertion order). Finally, loop until the user enters a valid grade and then display the corresponding GPA. Like,

```
Map<String, Double> gradeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
gradeMap.put("A", 4.0);
gradeMap.put("A-", 3.7);
gradeMap.put("B+", 3.3);
gradeMap.put("B", 3.0);
gradeMap.put("B-", 2.7);
gradeMap.put("C+", 2.3);
gradeMap.put("C", 2.0);
gradeMap.put("C-", 1.7);
gradeMap.put("D+", 1.3);
gradeMap.put("D-", 1.0);
gradeMap.put("F", 0.0);
System.out.printf("What grade did you earn in the class: %s?%n",
        gradeMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

String firstGrade = scanner.nextLine();
while (!gradeMap.containsKey(firstGrade)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please type a valid letter grade");
    firstGrade = scanner.nextLine();
}
System.out.printf("Your GPA from %s is a %.1f%n", firstClass, 
    gradeMap.get(firstGrade));
```

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for putting this together. Being a beginner, I was not aware of the capabilities of 'Map' and 'LinkedHashMap.' I remember finding a result of this used in C# but not JAVA, so this is great. Thank you for making the rest of this project pretty easy since it all duplicates for each class. I'll make sure to read more into 'Map' and it's capabilities.

Comment: Just revisited this project again today, so far everything works great. I would like to, however, store the GPA points earned from each class in a variable. One variable for each class that I could add altogether at the end to get the student's final semester GPA. How would this be done? I guess I don't understand what "%s?%n" means and what is going on with "Your GPA from %s is a %.1f%n".

Comment: [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: Thank you Elliot, that helps alittle. Here is what I'm talking about though. 'System.out.printf("Your GPA from %s is a %.1f%n", secondClass, 
       gradeMap.get(secondGrade));' How would I store the GPA value from that result for that class in a variable to be used later?

Comment: Thanks Elliott, so that's where I would assign a variable to store the GPA point value. I've learned alot from this project and using Map in all. Thanks for everything.